# How to set custom height & width for select enhanced with selectize.js jquery plugin?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, jquery-plugins, selectize.js

I'm using https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js in a project and I'm not able to customize the height and width of the select input:

- modifing the select via css not works
- there is not height / width options in https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md

The problem is aggravated because the standard select / text input (using bootstrap 2) is 30px height, and with this plug-in it grows to 37px and breaks very bad the visual of my user interface (growing all inputs to 37px is certainly not an option).

I've also included the selectize.bootstrap2.css file with no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

selectize.js customization for 30px height

```
.selectize-dropdown, .selectize-input { 
  line-height: 14px; 
}
```

Comment: Why the double `.selectize-input` selector?